# keystore signature not working android

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore

I have been working on an application for quite a while without any problem. Two weeks ago I then generated a keystore to sign my application. As a matter of fact I develop on two machines at home and in my office.
Since I generated the keystore I keep getting this message whenever I change the machine:

```
    Installation failed since the device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.
In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

Thanks

Comment: uninstall the application which is having same package name as this.

Comment: @jankigadhiya That would not be a good idea since my data will all be gone.

Comment: means you are having two different keystores?? @edmond

Comment: U have to uninstall the previous version or make an APK with same signature or keystore.

Comment: you have to uninstall it in order to install same apk compiled from different machine. If you don't want that then you have to keep different package name

Comment: @jankigadhiya I have generated one keystore that I have saved once in my computer at home and once at my office. And I use that keystore to sign the application

Comment: You can have only one keystore per application. You should bring that "home keystore" to office. The solution to your problem is simply Uninstall the previous app. Or build your office `App` with `Home keystore`. @edmond

Comment: @jankigadhiya The keystore is the same one. I generated it with my office machine and saved one copy in my home computer.

Comment: and you are using the same ?? still its giving error?? or you have regenerated one of them.?

Comment: @jankigadhiya I have generated a new keystore on my linux machine (at work) and saved it on my USB flash drive. I have used that same key on my  windows machine (at home) with no success.

Comment: please verify the key password and keystore password once.